# Is it possible to make this code run faster with lower iterations?

Tags: c

I need help with optimizing this code, with fewer iterations and to run faster.

```
void ImageBlur(Image img, int dx, int dy) {
    uint8* pixel = img->pixel;
    size_t imgWidth = (size_t)img->width;
    size_t imgHeight = (size_t)img->height;

    for (size_t y = 0; y < imgHeight; ++y) {
        for (size_t x = 0; x < imgWidth; ++x) {
            int sum = 0;
            int count = 0;

            size_t baseIndex = y * imgWidth + x;
            uint8* basePixel = pixel + baseIndex;

            for (int j = -dy; j <= dy; ++j) {
                size_t ny = y + j;
                if (ny < imgHeight) {
                    int rowOffset = j * imgWidth;
                    uint8* rowStart = basePixel + rowOffset;

                    for (int i = -dx; i <= dx; ++i) {
                        size_t nx = x + i;
                        if (nx < imgWidth) {
                            sum += rowStart[i];
                            count++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if (count > 0) {
                int average = sum / count;
                *basePixel = (uint8)average;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens when i or j are less than zero?  Isn't the blur using pixels that have already been adjusted?  As for your question, pre-calculations, threads.  If you fix the routine so that it populates a new image rather than overwriting the original (which also solves using new pixel data instead of original pixel data), you can create a lot of threads and many calculations can be saved so that the blur can be re-iterated.

Comment: @BradLanam unsigned values 'wrap' in a well defined way, and `if (ny < imgHeight)` will be false.

Comment: @WeatherVane, got it. thanks.  I never code in that fashion.

Comment: @BradLanam I originally posted a similar comment about range checking :)

Answer (score 3):

> Possible to make this code run faster with lower iterations?

Yes.  The key is to focus on reducing [O()](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).
This often means more code though.

**Correct functionality?**

Before trying to make faster, it is really correct to read pixel data that has already been *blurred*?
I'd expect a separate burred image destination from the source.

**Take middle advantage**

Code the edges differently from the middle as the middle constitutes the majority of the time and the number of checks can be reduced.

**Take row advantage**

As code marches across a row, the sum formed via `for (int i = -dx; i <= dx; ++i) { ... sum += rowStart[i];` is the same sum as for the prior pixel except for the left and right values.  This is very valuable when `dx` is large. Keep a running sum that subtracts the old left and adds the new right.

**Take column advantage**

This above row trick applies to the rows before and after (based on `dy`).  Keep track of `2*dy + 1` running sums.

**Impose limits**

As is, `dx, dy` can be for more than `imgWidth, imgHeight`.  This adds code complexity.  Consider limiting to less than 1/2 than half the corresponding dimension.

Also the `sum` type needed is about `pixel_max * dy+1 * dx+1 * 4`.  I suggest rejecting any blur attempt the could overflow `unsigned sum`.

As code uses an `unsigned` wrap trick for edge testing, `imgWidth + dx` needs to be `< UINT_MAX/2`.  (Test in the y direction too) Suggest simply tests up front.  Remember good code gets used for tasks far larger than we first intend.

**Minor: `size_t`?**

Candidate linear improvement: If `img->width` is type `int`, consider `unsigned` rather than `size_t`.

---

All in all, rather than OP's `O(imgHeight * imgWidth * dx * dy)`,
we can go to `O((imgHeight * imgWidth) + (dx * dy))`.

Comment: Could you write the code?

Comment: @Rawer of course I could, yet at $50+/hour better if you write and Stackoverflow critiques.

Comment: What is the O() if this current code?

Comment: @Rawer, O() of current code -->  In the answer's last point: `O(imgHeight * imgWidth * dx * dy)`.

Comment: This is exactly the technique I used as part of a patent in 1989: https://patents.justia.com/patent/4811414 .  It had to run on a 25 Mhz processor, speed was critical.

Comment: @MarkRansom Interesting!

Comment: @Rawer Rather than thanks, review [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and after a few days, act on it.